# building Role based application

Tags: php, mysql, roles, tracking

I have to make a small website

where I have 7 type of users. which can login into system.

some of users have permissions to only add equipments and others can add/edit. some of them can only view.

There will be some common fields for all users  adding equipments in system and some fields will be user specific.

I have to track all changes in equipments with user changing equipments.

Can any one explain what will be best way to do this job.

Way in the sense table structure for users and tracking changes in equipments and users tracking for both login and what changes done by them.

Am using php and mysql database.

I don't want to go for CMS,Frameworks. It's a small application.

Comment: i suggest you start looking at a framework be it either Zend , CackePHP , Codeigniter ... it will be easyer to get the app started and most of them allready have implementation for an ACL role system

Comment: possible duplicate of [Question regarding PHP possibilites (users, admin/mod)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369650/question-regarding-php-possibilites-users-admin-mod)

Comment: @pradeep : Don't comment if u can't understand question.

Comment: Ya agree with poelinca when these things are already available by experts then why people still want to start it on own from scratch. In fact they save alot of time and provide a better way to handle possible conditions

Comment: It's a small application.I don't want to go towards CMS,Frameworks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you are going to need a [role-based access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RBAC) system.  Developing one is not really a trivial task, so as already suggested, finding a framework or ready-made class that does the job would be a worthwhile start.

However, there's plenty of information out there on how to create one.  Here's a few links to get you started:

**Stackoverflow**

[Role Based Access Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113543/role-based-access-control)
<s>[Role-based access to pages in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963455/role-based-access-to-pages-in-php)</s> (dead link)

**Other sites**

[A Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) system for PHP](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/role-based-access-control.html)
[Fine Grained Role Based Access Control (RBAC) system](http://www.sqlrecipes.com/database_design/fine_grained_role_based_access_control_rbac_system-3/)
[Patterns Tutorial Series (part 1): RBAC Domain Model](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?threadid=162027)

A search for *PHP RBAC* will no doubt reveal many more.